# Youtube Data API V3 HttpError 400 and returned "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key."

Tags: youtube, google-colaboratory

I hvae tried to get Thumbnail on youtube in google colab.
excuted commnad: !pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
And I excuted code but I got a error that http bad request.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efkzq.png)

I expected to get some data.
Thank you in advance.